# does BCP queryout use indexes?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm running BCP against a table of 112m rows to select approx 1.6m

The table definition has a 25 x nvarchar(10) , 20 x INT columns  and 2 Bit columns. It also has 1 non persisted compute column, which is nvarch(14) casting 2 int columns into a string. It has a clustered index on the computed column and one other index on an INT column (which is used in the where clause)

```
bcp "select * from db.dbo.table where src = 1002" queryout F:/path/1002_1638762.dat -n -U ausername -P *********
```

judging by the performance - 20 minutes - it looks as tho the query is running a scan, This conclusion is also supported by the fact that when the output file reaches its end size, the read continues for sometime.

Does bcp use indexes? I would be expecting this to run much faster using an index seek and key lookup?

Can anyone recommend any performance improvements?

Comment: You want to ensure that "src" has an index on it.  Otherwise writing 1.6 million rows is going to take some time, particularly if "F:" is not a local drive.  How fast does the select run if you run it normally as a query?

Comment: hi @SQLDBA, thanks... the src column is indexed as per the Q "and one other index on an INT column (which is used in the where clause)", F is a local drive, the query runs in  about 2.20 in SQL SMS

Comment: I have never tried, but I would assume you can use query hints with BCP, or at least you could try what happens if you add index hint there.

Comment: interestingly @JamesZ if I run just the query with query hint I get the execution plan I'd expect (Index seek + key lookup) but when I include it in the bcp queryout statement I get an error "query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query" with recommendation to resubmit the query with specifying any hints.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to answer the question "does BCP queryout use indexes" - ostensibly it does seem to, but whether it creating optimal execution plans I didn't find an answer to.

However, I did find a performance enhancement with a change to my approach:

- select the rows into a new table
- bcp out the new table
- drop the new table

Completes in less than 2 minutes.